# Ridge estimator for orthogonal basis

Tags: ridge-regression

In the book "Elements of Statistical Learning", the author compares the OSL estimator with Lasso, Ridge and Best Subset for the special case of Orthogonal X. I am attaching the particular estimator. [image]In the plot, the author draws red dotted line as the estimator. For ridge estimator, why the line gets shifted from the grey line if it's just scaling? Should it be actually drawn to be the same as the grey line?

Comment: A line with slope $1/(1+\lambda)$ will never coincide with a line of slope $1$ (the 45 degree gray lines) unless $\lambda=0.$

Comment: ah, so the picture is drawing y vs x? and the estimators are the slope?

Comment: It's a bit of a puzzle, because the axes unfortunately are unlabeled; but as far as I can tell, each plot takes a particular value of $\lambda$ and graphs the adjusted estimator as a function of $\hat\beta_j.$  The purpose is to give you a sense of how the adjustment works for each of the three estimators.

Comment: I see, thanks so much!